# Comparing multiple fields of 2 list of different objects

Tags: java, list, stream, compare

I have two objects, both have 4 similar fields that I need to compare and I get them from different sources as a list of objects. I want to make sure that there is at least one matching object in both list, as in they have the exact same fields. The issues is that they can be in different order. I have this code where I have two for loops

```
for(Object1 object1 : list1){
    bool match = false;
    for(Object2 object2 : list2){
        if(object1.getField1().equal(object2.getField1()) && etc etc..){
             match = true;
             break;
        }
    }
    if(!match)
        return false
}
return true;
```

Basically I iterate through all of list2 to see if there is at least one match row that has all the same fields in object1, if there is none, then I return false, if there is a matching row then I move on to the next row until I check all of the rows in list1.

I do not like this way of checking and I was wondering if there is an easier way of checking this. I have heard of using Stream in java 8 but I cannot think of a way of using in this scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you write the classes that define the objects in each of the lists?

Comment: @BillHorvath, I'm confuse, do you mean like a toString for one of the Objects? Or a class to get each object in a list?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. Each object in the list is an instance of a class with four fields. Did you write the class? Or is it from a library like java.util, org.springframework, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
boolean isMatchs = list1.stream()
        .allMatch(el1 -> list2.stream().anyMatch(el2 -> equals(el1, el2)));
```

with static method equals like this:

```
static boolean equals(Object1 a, Object2 b) {
    return Objects.equals(a.getField1(), b.getField1());// && ...
}
```